# AngularJS - how to export content of a directive (ng-repeat) into separate downloadable HTML file

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

As in the title: How can I use Angular to allow downloading the content of a div (ng-repeat directive in this case) in a new HTML file?

I have tried this:

```
var content = 'file content';
var blob = new Blob([ content ], { type : 'text/html' });
$scope.url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL( blob );
```

HTML:

```
<a download="content.txt" ng-href="{{ url }}">download</a>
```

but it doesn't work.

I know how to achieve in pure JS, but I was wondering if there is some shorter, handy way of achieving that with Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to output the table as a file for the user to download.

```
<div id="exportable">
    <table width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>DoB</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                <td>{{item.email}}</td>
                <td>{{item.dob | date:'MM/dd/yy'}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Export call:

```
var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
        type: "text/html;charset=utf-8"
    });
    saveAs(blob, "content.html");
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XNVj3/108/